Is the Arens space symmetrizable?
This is intended to be a self-answering question, which is allowed on StackExchange sites (see here).
The Arens space is defined as follows: Let $X = \omega \cup \{\infty\}$ be the one-point compactification of $\omega$. The Arens space $S_2$ has underlying set $(X \times \omega) \cup \{\infty'\}$. The topology is defined via the following closure operator: For any $A \subset X$,
$$\overline{A} = K_1 \cup K_2 \cup K_3$$
where $K_1 = A \cap (\omega \times \omega)$; $K_2 = (A \cap (\{\infty\} \times \omega)) \cup (\{\infty\} \times B)$, where $B = \{n < \omega: |A \cap (\omega \times \{n\})| = \infty\}$; and $K_3 = \varnothing$ if $\infty' \notin A$ and $K_2$ is finite, and $K_3 = \{\infty'\}$ otherwise.
To put it another way, any point of $\omega \times \omega$ is isolated. For $n < \omega$, $(\infty, n)$ has local basis $(m, \infty] \times \{n\}$ for $m < \omega$. For $\infty'$, it has local basis,
$$\{\infty'\} \cup \left(\bigcup_{i = m+1}^\infty (n_i, \infty] \times \{i\}\right), m < \omega \text{ and for each }i > m, n_i < \omega$$
Recall that a symmetric on a set $X$ is a function $d: X^2 \to [0, \infty)$ which is reflexive, i.e., $d(x, y) = 0$ iff $x = y$; and symmetric, i.e., $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$ for any $x, y \in X$. The difference from a metric is that it needs not satisfy the triangle inequality. A topological space $X$ is called symmetrizable if there is a symmetric $d$ on $X$ s.t. $U \subset X$ is open iff for every $x \in U$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $B(x, \epsilon) \subset U$. Here, $B(x, \epsilon) = \{y \in X: d(x, y) < \epsilon\}$. Note that $B(x, \epsilon)$ itself needs not be open. Note also that given any symmetric $d$ on a set $X$, $d$ naturally generates a symmetrizable topology on $X$ by declaring $U \subset X$ is open iff for every $x \in U$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $B(x, \epsilon) \subset U$.

Is the Arens space symmetrizable?


Yes, the Arens space is symmetrizable. We will define a symmetric $d$ on $S_2$ as follows:

$d(x, y) = 0$ if $x = y$;
The distance between $(\infty, m)$ and $(n, m)$ is $\frac{1}{n+1}$, where $n,m < \omega$;
The distance between $(\infty, m)$ and $\infty'$ is $\frac{1}{m+1}$, where $m < \omega$;
The distance between any other pair of points is $1$.

We claim that the given topology $\tau$ on $S_2$ coincides with the topology $\tau_d$ generated by $d$. In particular, $\tau$ is symmetrizable. For any $(n,m) \in \omega \times \omega$, it is indeed $\tau_d$-isolated as $B((n,m), \frac{1}{n+1}) = \{(n,m)\}$. For any $(\infty, n)$, let $U \subset S_2$ be a $\tau_d$-open neighborhood of $(\infty, n)$. Then $U$ contains $B((\infty, n), \frac{1}{k+1})$ for some $k < \omega$, which includes $(m,n)$ for $m>k$, i.e., $U$ contains a basic open neighborhood of $(\infty, n)$ under $\tau$. Conversely, let $(m, \infty] \times \{n\}$, $m < \omega$, be a basic open neighborhood of $(\infty, n)$ under $\tau$. It is $\tau_d$-open since,
$$B((\infty, n), \min\{\frac{1}{m+1},\frac{1}{n+1}\}) \subset (m, \infty] \times \{n\}$$
And every point in $(m, \infty] \times \{n\}$ other than $(\infty, n)$ is $\tau_d$-isolated.
Finally, for $\infty'$, let $U \subset S_2$ be a $\tau_d$-open neighborhood of $\infty'$. Then $U$ contains $B(\infty', \frac{1}{m+1})$ for some $m < \infty$, which includes $\{\infty\} \times (m,\infty)$. Moreover, for every $m+1\leq i<\omega$, as $(\infty, i) \in U$, $U$ must contain $B((\infty, i), \frac{1}{n_i+1})$ for some $n_i < \infty$. The latter set contains $(n_i, \infty] \times \{i\}$. Thus, $U$ contains a basic open neighborhood of $\infty'$ under $\tau$.
Conversely, let $U = \{\infty'\} \cup \left(\bigcup_{i = m+1}^\infty (n_i, \infty] \times \{i\}\right)$, $m < \omega$ and for each $i > m$, $n_i < \omega$, be a basic open neighborhood of $\infty'$ under $\tau$. Then $B(\infty', \frac{1}{m+1}) \subset U$. For each $i > m$, $B((\infty, i), \frac{1}{n_i+1}) \subset U$. And every point in $U$ other than $\infty'$ and $(\infty, i)$ for $i > m$ is $\tau_d$-isolated. Thus, $U$ is $\tau_d$-open.

This is an interesting example.  The Arens-Fort space is the subspace $Y=(\omega\times\omega)\cup{\infty'}\subseteq S_2$.  Even though the Arens space is symmetrizable, the restriction of $d$ to $Y$, which is a symmetric on $Y$, does not generate the subspace topology on $Y$.  In fact, $Y$ is not symmetrizable.

@PatrickR Indeed. It is clear why this happens: the symmetric only ensures points in $\omega \times \omega$ converge to points in ${\infty} \times \omega$, which then converge to $\infty'$. But no sequence in $\omega \times \omega$ can itself converge to $\omega'$. Without points in ${\infty} \times \omega$ acting as intermediaries, the space fails to be even sequential. But it is still quite surprising that being symmetrizable is not hereditary, especially considering that being semimetrizable is hereditary.
